# How to subset a df in several df using date dates in a second df in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a long df with date values every 5 seconds and CO2 concentration values from a continuous monitoring. Those values need to be calibrated with data provided in a second df that store initial and final dates, and the calibration parameter that I need to use.

Calibration parameters change with time. The steps I need to perform are:

1. Split df1 in several df as rows in df 2 according initial date and final date,
2. Apply the calibration parameter suplied  in each row of df2,
3. Rebuild the initial df to store calibrated data.

I'm strugling trying to split df1 acording to df2 in R, I tried a for bucle that did not work and I'm convinced I need to use a more straightforward approach like `split()` or `apply()`.

[map of the actions I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drMpO.png)

Since the data is too big I give minimal example, it looks like:

| DateTime | CO2 |
| --- | --- |
| 14-05-2022 00:19:50 | 479.8340879 |
| 14-05-2022 00:19:55 | 479.836915 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:00 | 479.8462298 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:05 | 479.8417516 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:10 | 479.823782 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:15 | 479.8069912 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:20 | 479.7700943 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:25 | 479.7807222 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:30 | 479.7696609 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:35 | 479.7580641 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:40 | 479.7799673 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:45 | 479.8502333 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:50 | 479.9433364 |
| 14-05-2022 00:20:55 | 480.0223177 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:00 | 480.115519 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:05 | 480.1925293 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:10 | 480.2117073 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:15 | 480.3010663 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:20 | 480.3629772 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:25 | 480.464677 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:30 | 480.5220228 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:35 | 480.5644807 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:40 | 480.6019965 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:45 | 480.6793977 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:50 | 480.7235118 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:55 | 480.7624506 |
| 14-05-2022 00:22:00 | 480.7887041 |
| 14-05-2022 00:22:05 | 480.7656519 |
| 14-05-2022 00:22:10 | 480.7710211 |
| 14-05-2022 00:22:15 | 480.7655103 |
| 14-05-2022 00:22:20 | 480.7906543 |
| 14-05-2022 00:22:25 | 480.7992506 |
| 14-05-2022 00:22:30 | 480.7758722 |

And the calibration df2 could be

| date_initial | date_final | calib_parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14-05-2022 00:00:00 | 14-05-2022 00:20:59 | 0.98 |
| 14-05-2022 00:21:00 | 14-05-2022 00:21:59 | 0.99 |
| 14-05-2022 00:22:00 | 14-05-2022 00:22:59 | 0.97 |

and I need to multiply by diferent calib parameters values in df1 that are between `date_initial` and `date_final` in df2

Comment: Hi Carme, and welcome to SO! 

If you can include a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, it will be easier to see where you're at now and help you move forward.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the 2nd data frame: is it the case that each chunk of time has exactly 1 calibration parameter associated with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create new variable based on time and preexisting variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485767/how-to-create-new-variable-based-on-time-and-preexisting-variables)

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot for your answer, i included some data from my df so you can visualize the data. The calibration df is more complex than a simple multiplication by a parameter but it would be much complex to expose the whole problem. Right now it's my difficulty selecting different parts of one df based on another df that's keeping me from moving forward.

Comment: Hi Carme, thanks for the example data! if you can add the data with `dput` that would be even better... 
It sounds like something like this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51283920/8400969

Comment: Thanks Michael, it could work for my question but the true is that I need to be able to store and analize separated df, otherwise the computational time of analizing row by row is to long, and also I need to apply a calibration curve that I skiped in the example for simplification. I really need to break it in df and operate them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the `{fuzzyjoin}` package, which lets you join datasets by date.

The strategy is:

1. Join `df2` to `df1` wherever `df1$DateTime` is between `df2$date_initial` and `df2$date_final`.
2. Multiply `CO2` by the calibration factor.
3. If necessary, delete any extra columns.

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
df1 <- fuzzy_inner_join(df1, df2,
         by = c("DateTime" =  "date_initial",
                  "DateTime" = "date_final"), 
         match_fun = list(`>`, `<`)
       )
df1$CO2 <- df1$CO2 * df1$calib_parameter
df1$calib_parameter <- NULL
```

This is basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51899547/10522567) answer, but with a small correction. You might also find some of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934361/merge-2-dataframes-if-value-within-range) answers helpful.